# Submitting application to Apple store - application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone

I tried to upload my iPhone application to the App store, but received the following error: **The binary you uploaded was invalid. The icon file must be in .png format.**
The icon file IS in .png format, size 57x57, so assumed it is a bug and tried to upload with Application Uploader, when I got another error:
**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.**

I followed every single step, and it is not working... it is driving me crazy! Please advise what should I do!

Answer (score 2):

First, check that the icon file is in .png format, rather than .PNG format.

Second, take some deep breaths, look out a window for a few minutes, and then go back over the steps to upload your iPhone application.

Answer (score 1):

Many people were confusing (like me) modifying the code signing property of XCode. 
You must ensure that your code signing identity property start with

**iPhone Distribution : Developer Name**

instead of

**iPhone Developer : Developer Name**

PS : If you have no option start with iPhone distribution, you didn't get production certificate yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned anything regarding the fact that you did sign the code, I'm going to assume you didn't.

You'll need to get your application code signed in order for it to be accepted, so that the phone knows it's from a trusted developer, and not just a virus someone has uploaded.

Do you have a code signing certificate?